# QDir change directory to start another program from main qt program

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I have two project in a vs 2013 solution. The first project is s a command line project and the other project is the user interface that allow the user to select various options and calls the first project.

```
solution
--Project1 ( console)
---Debug folder
--Project2 ( GUI)
```

in `qt` i use the following code to start `project1 ( console)`

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QDir::setCurrent("build/GPURenderDemo/Debug");
std::cout << QDir::currentPath().toStdString() <<endl;

process->start(QString::fromStdString(getConstructedArgs()));
```

however the project1 dosen't get executed and the `QDir::currentPath()` returns nonsence data.

```
D:/******/build/GUI0000000063F0A785
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the working directory of the `QProcess` directly, see `QProcess::setWorkingDirectory()`

Answer (score 0):

`QDir::setCurrent` sets the working directory of the current process, is this what you meant? Also, it returns a bool so you can see whether it succeeded, always worth checking.

You can set the working directory of the console process you're starting with `QProcess::setWorkingDirectory`.

I don't think we can help more without further details of your intentions.

Comment: My intention is to access the debug folder of the first project and start it. my problem is finding the path to debug folder of the first project.  The **absolute folder path** works but i want to pass the **relative folder path of the debug folder** of my first project

Comment: I don't fully understand, however the following might be of use: `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath` (gets the directory in which the program executable lives) and `QDir::relativeFilePath` (gets a relative path to another file or directory.